# Move elements with CSS

Tags: css

How would *YOU* change the CSS to move this to another part of the page?

Here is the image I'm using: http://www.frysa.us/switch.gif

The function:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready( function(){ 
$(".cb-enable").click(function(){
    var parent = $(this).parents('.switch');
    $('.cb-disable',parent).removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $('.checkbox',parent).attr('checked', true);
});
$(".cb-disable").click(function(){
    var parent = $(this).parents('.switch');
    $('.cb-enable',parent).removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $('.checkbox',parent).attr('checked', false);
});
});
```

The repeating nature of the .gif  seems to mess up the positioning for me.

I'd like it to appear over to the right a little more

```
<style type="text/css">
* { margin: 0; padding: 0: }

body { font-family: Arial, Sans-serif; }
.cb-enable, .cb-disable, .cb-enable span, .cb-disable span { background: url
(switch.gif) repeat-x; display: block;float: left;}  
.cb-enable span, .cb-disable span { line-height: 30px; display: block; background-
repeat: no-repeat; font-weight: bold; }
.cb-enable span { background-position: left -90px; padding: 0 10px; }
.cb-disable span { background-position: right -180px;padding: 0 10px; }
.cb-disable.selected { background-position: 0 -30px; }
.cb-disable.selected span { background-position: right -210px; color: #fff; }
.cb-enable.selected { background-position: 0 -60px; }
.cb-enable.selected span { background-position: left -150px; color: #fff; }
 .switch label { cursor: pointer; }

 </style>
```

Comment: show us the html, even better a live version, and tell us what goes wrong..

Comment: repeat-x .. but you may need to ask specific question.

Comment: Thanks for the comeback. Here's the regular one: [link](http://www.frysa.us/experiment.htm) in this one here is the code line: .cb-enable, .cb-disable, .cb-enable span, .cb-disable span { background: url (switch.gif) repeat-x; display: block;float: left;}
Here is my adjusted one: [link](http://www.frysa.us/MyAdjustedExperiment.htm)  and here is the adjusted CSS:
 .cb-enable, .cb-disable, .cb-enable span, .cb-disable span { background: url (switch.gif) repeat-x; display:block;position:relative;left:120px;}
And here is the image: [link](http://www.frysa.us/switch.gif)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to move it to the right by 120 pixels, give your element (right now it's the paragraph tag) an ID and do this:

```
#switchingButton{
    margin-left: 120px;
}
```

You can use padding-left: 120px; as well if your design would require padding rather than margin.

Comment: Thanks. That worked out great. Now I can move it about the page.
I've been at this HTML, CSS and Javascript for about a year. But I seem to be a bit of a "slow learner". Appreciate the help